# Change fill color on vector asset in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

Android Studio now supports vector assets on 21+ and will generate pngs for lower versions at compile time.  I have a vector asset (from the Material Icons) that I want to change the fill color.  This works on 21+, but the generated pngs do not change color.  Is there a way to do this?

```
<vector android:height="48dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="48dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="@color/primary" android:pathData="M9,16.17L4.83,12l-1.42,1.41L9,19 21,7l-1.41,-1.41z"/>
```

Answer (score 417, accepted):

Don't edit the vector assets directly. If you're using a vector drawable in an ImageButton, just choose your color in `android:tint`.

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/primary" />
```

Comment: tinting only works on 21+ devices, do you have any suggestion for pre-lollipop devices

Comment: android:tint works on all android versions since APIv1. What you mean is drawableTint.

Comment: `android:tint` must be after `android:src`

Comment: What about `drawableLeft` in `Button`?

Comment: @mudit try using a vector with fillColor="#colorvalue", don't use a @ color reference because they only work SDK 21+ for vectors (so not for the generated PNG's)

Comment: What if I'm using this asset in a menu Item? @PieterAelse

Comment: @MichaelObi Not sure, just try on both pre-SDK21 and SDK21+

Comment: you must use app:srcCompat instead of android:src for supporting pre-lolipop devices

Comment: @MichaelObi This is the same question I had. There is no android:tint attribute for an `item` in a menu .xml file.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess Why does `tint` have to go after `src`? That makes no sense, attributes are loaded in the order that Java code is written... See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java#205 (tint) and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java#188 (src)
Am I missing something?

Comment: @milosmns ok, I commented that more than a year ago, it might have been a bug, I do not remember, but it should be as you say. The bug might have to do with the fact that vectors have colors loaded as properties of the elements inside.

Comment: @YYYY-MM-DD Why not change the fillColor directly on the vector asset?
I mean, I know that I can apply a tint programmatically or through xml attributes, but if I want my drawables to all be white, why not change the fill color instead of keeping them black and applying a tint?
Is there any advantage in keeping the vector drawables with a black fill color?

Comment: Try this to changes color programmatically  "imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorSelected), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);" And make sure  to add this "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" in build.gradle

Answer (score 109):

You can do it.

BUT you cannot use @color references for colors (..lame), otherwise it will work only for L+

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFAABB"
    android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zm-6,0C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z"/>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! @color references don't work in vectors pre-Lollipop (so vector -> PNG conversion)
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186431

Comment: @color references can now be used for the fillColor attribute for all Android versions, however it does not support color state lists.

Comment: It looks like the way to do vector state lists is with [AnimatedStateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedStateListDrawable.html)s

Comment: @TheIT what do I have to enable it? Doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: @PieterAelse I'm not sure, what if you want to use the same asset but with different backgrounds(tints like in previous answer). In your solution you will have several instances of same resource but with different fill color

Comment: @AntonMakov yes, ofc its only for static things

Comment: @PieterAelse, I'm able to refer color references and it's working fine API 19. e.g. `android:fillColor="@color/icon_color"`

Comment: does not work iven when setting color directly. Still white.

Answer (score 74):

As said in other answers, don't edit the vector drawable directly, instead you can tint in java code, like that:

```
    mWrappedDrawable = mDrawable.mutate();
    mWrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mWrappedDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(mWrappedDrawable, mColor);
    DrawableCompat.setTintMode(mWrappedDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

And for the sake of simplicity, I have created a helper class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * {@link Drawable} helper class.
 *
 * @author Filipe Bezerra
 * @version 18/01/2016
 * @since 18/01/2016
 */
public class DrawableHelper {
    @NonNull Context mContext;
    @ColorRes private int mColor;
    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private Drawable mWrappedDrawable;

    public DrawableHelper(@NonNull Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static DrawableHelper withContext(@NonNull Context context) {
        return new DrawableHelper(context);
    }

    public DrawableHelper withDrawable(@DrawableRes int drawableRes) {
        mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, drawableRes);
        return this;
    }

    public DrawableHelper withDrawable(@NonNull Drawable drawable) {
        mDrawable = drawable;
        return this;
    }

    public DrawableHelper withColor(@ColorRes int colorRes) {
        mColor = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, colorRes);
        return this;
    }

    public DrawableHelper tint() {
        if (mDrawable == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("É preciso informar o recurso drawable pelo método withDrawable()");
        }

        if (mColor == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("É necessário informar a cor a ser definida pelo método withColor()");
        }

        mWrappedDrawable = mDrawable.mutate();
        mWrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mWrappedDrawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(mWrappedDrawable, mColor);
        DrawableCompat.setTintMode(mWrappedDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        return this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void applyToBackground(@NonNull View view) {
        if (mWrappedDrawable == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("É preciso chamar o método tint()");
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            view.setBackground(mWrappedDrawable);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(mWrappedDrawable);
        }
    }

    public void applyTo(@NonNull ImageView imageView) {
        if (mWrappedDrawable == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("É preciso chamar o método tint()");
        }

        imageView.setImageDrawable(mWrappedDrawable);
    }

    public void applyTo(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (mWrappedDrawable == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("É preciso chamar o método tint()");
        }

        menuItem.setIcon(mWrappedDrawable);
    }

    public Drawable get() {
        if (mWrappedDrawable == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("É preciso chamar o método tint()");
        }

        return mWrappedDrawable;
    }
}
```

To use just do the following:

```
    DrawableHelper
            .withContext(this)
            .withColor(R.color.white)
            .withDrawable(R.drawable.ic_search_24dp)
            .tint()
            .applyTo(mSearchItem);
```

Or:

```
    final Drawable drawable = DrawableHelper
            .withContext(this)
            .withColor(R.color.white)
            .withDrawable(R.drawable.ic_search_24dp)
            .tint()
            .get();

    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
```

Comment: Hi Filipe, thanks for your answer. Do you have a library, snipped code github where we can see the license? thanks :)

Comment: Nope Vicent, no license at all. The solution it's so simple that I guess the Builder pattern used here isn't necessary. But anyone can be benefit of this solution and use without license.

Comment: Great answer! Works exactly like I need

Comment: @VincentD. The SO web page footer says "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required"

Comment: It worked for me with some changes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A 1° vez que vejo um brasileiro no StackOverflow e o cara me salva haha Vlw velho me poupou um bom tempo!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 47):

To change vector image color you can directly use **android:tint="@color/colorAccent"**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivVectorImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
```

To change color **programatically**

```
ImageView ivVectorImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivVectorImage);
ivVectorImage.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: getColor() is deprecated

Comment: How to use it for TextView's drawable*** ?

Comment: getColor(ResId) is deprecated @David, but `getColor(ResId, Theme)` is not. Or you can use `ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.primary, null);` if you don’t care about the theme… or if your context/policy delegate IS an activity, you can do `getTheme()` for that last parameter.

Answer (score 16):

Currently the working soloution is 
  android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"

Nothing worked for me except hard coding in the vector

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
      android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zm-6,0C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z"/>
```

However, fillcolor and tint might work soon. Please see this discussion for more information:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186431

Also the colors mighr stick in the cache so deleting app for all users might help.

Answer (score 12):

### Update: `AppCompat` support

Other answers suspecting if `android:tint` will work on only 21+ devices only, **AppCompat(*v23.2.0 and above*)** now provides a backward compatible handling of tint attribute.

So, the course of action would be to use `AppCompatImageView` and `app:srcCompat`(in AppCompat namespace) instead of `android:src`(Android namespace).

Here is an example(AndroidX: This is *androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView* ;)):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/credits_material_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:tint="#ffd2ee"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dollar_coin_stack" />
```

And don't forget to enable vector drawable support in gradle:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Comment: Just an update. Nowadays the `AppCompatImageView` is under `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView`

Answer (score 7):

Android studio now supports vectors pre-lollipop. No PNG conversion. You can still change your fill color and it will work.

In you ImageView, use

```
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_24dp"
```

In your gradle file,

```
 // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
   }  
 }  

 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Comment: The question is "how to change vector fill colour", not "how to use vector asset"

Answer (score 4):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="//Your Color Code//">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M11,9.16V2c-5,0.5 -9,4.79 -9,10s4,9.5 9"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the easiest way to change the color. android:tint = "//Your Color Code//"

Answer (score 3):

If the vectors are not showing individually set colors using fillColor then they may be being set to a default widget parameter.

Try adding `app:itemIconTint="@color/lime"` to activity_main.xml to set a default color type for the widget icons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/lime"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[VectorDrawable @ developers.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)

Comment: In Android studio 3.6 change in svg xml this field: android:fillColor="#FFFFC400"

Answer (score 2):

Add this library to the Gradle to enable color vector drawable in old android Devices.

```
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

and re sync gradle. I think it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For my ImageButton, I used `app:tint="@color/green"` instead of `android:tint`

Answer (score 1):

if you look to support old version pre lolipop

use the same xml code with some changes

instead of normal `ImageView --> AppCompatImageView`

instead of `android:src      --> app:srcCompat`

here is example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/primary" />
```

dont forget update your gradle as @ **Sayooj Valsan** mention

> ```
> // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
>  android {  
>    defaultConfig {  
>      vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
>    }  
>  }  
>
>  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
> ```

**Notice**  To any one use vector dont ever ever never give your vector reference to color like this one `android:fillColor="@color/primary"` give its hex value .

Comment: why never use `@color` for `fillcolor` ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to you MainActivity.java
and below this code 
 -> `NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);`
Add single line of code -> `navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);`
i.e. the last line of my code

I hope this might solve your problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those not using an `ImageView`, the following worked for me on a plain `View` (and hence the behaviour should replicate on any kind of view)

```
<View
    android:background="@drawable/ic_reset"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLightText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of an item vector icon you can use this:

```
android:iconTint="@color/color"
```

Comment: Only API 26 and higher

Answer (score 0):

If the vector asset is within a CardView, try
`card_view:tint="@color/secondary"` within the ImageView.
Note: Replace `@color/secondary` with your desired color.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:drawableTint="@color/primary"
```

in activity_main.xml

[image: activity_main.xml]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Kotlin version of Drawable Helper by `Filipe`

```
class DrawableHelper(var mContext: Context) {
    @ColorRes
    private var mColor = 0
    private lateinit var mDrawable: Drawable
    private lateinit var mWrappedDrawable: Drawable
    fun withDrawable(@DrawableRes drawableRes: Int): DrawableHelper {
        mDrawable = getDrawable(mContext, drawableRes)!!
        return this
    }

    fun withDrawable(drawable: Drawable): DrawableHelper {
        mDrawable = drawable
        return this
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    fun withColor(@ColorRes colorRes: Int): DrawableHelper {
        mColor = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, colorRes)
        return this
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    fun tint(): DrawableHelper {
        mWrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mWrappedDrawable)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(mWrappedDrawable, mColor)
        DrawableCompat.setTintMode(mWrappedDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        return this
    }

    fun applyToBackground(view: View) {
        view.background = mWrappedDrawable
    }

    fun applyTo(imageView: ImageView) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(mWrappedDrawable)
    }

    fun applyTo(menuItem: MenuItem) {
        menuItem.icon = mWrappedDrawable
    }

    fun get(): Drawable {
        return mWrappedDrawable
    }

    companion object {
        fun withContext(context: Context): DrawableHelper {
            return DrawableHelper(context)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a mistake in `tint()` method where instead of:
`mWrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mWrappedDrawable)`
you should have:
`mWrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mDrawable)`