# Build unsuccessful after adding resources, how to add resources in res folder?

Tags: android

I'm learning how to make android apps from book: "Android Programming for beginners" by John Horton. In chapter 12 I downloaded images and copied it to res directory as shown in the book. But there are some errors when I tried to sync gradle files. I think the directory structure was changed since the book was written. Can anyone point me to a resource where I can learn how to put resources in res directory?

PS: I'm using android studio.

Comment: What are these errors when you tried to sync gradle files?

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@android:color/white": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.

Comment: When you get an error or exception, first google it. Most probably someone else had this error before you, many times. See this question and answers. It may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32924986/3669559

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül that does not solve my question. I tried googleing but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create "drawable" folder inside /res folder for images.

Some other folders can have in the /res folder:

1. drawable/ - Bitmap files / Nine-Patches (re-sizable bitmaps) / State lists / Shapes / Animation drawables / Other drawables
2. layout/ - XML files that define a user interface layout.

Comment: That folder was already present in the resources I downloaded from https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline . There were some additional folders and xml files. None of which are working.

Comment: In which format you have downloaded image... PNG or other..?